# Java: Convert nested XMLString to a flat CSV with no POJO or stylesheet

Tags: java, xml, csv

here is my scenario:

1. I have a DB with millions of Rows containing an XMLblob column of varying size upto 50MB.
2. I dont have a stylesheet or a schema
3. All I have is a list of fieldnames that I need to fetch from these blobs.
4. I cannot create a POJO because these fieldnames input may change from run to run
5. these blobs may or may not contain all these fields.
6. So I have to parse these XML blobs, flatten them out, and fetch the necessary fields into a CSV file.
7. these fieldnames will be the columns in the CSV, and the values form XMLBlob will be the rows.
8. I am on java 8, and I cannot use any fancy libraries. Just openCSV or some basic XML libraries.

With the above requirements I am converting xml to json (so I can have a structure with the lack of POJO) and then to CSV as shown below:

```
JSONArray myJSONStringArray = new JSONArray();
List<byte[]> allMyBlobs = fetchAllBlobsFromDB();
for each blob {
    String myXmlStr = convertBlobToString();
    JSONObject jsonDoc = XML.toJSONObject(myXmlStr ).optJSONObject("document");
    JSONObject flattenedJSON = FlattenNestedJSONAndFetchFields(jsonDoc, requiredFieldNames);
    String jsonString = flattenedJSON.toString();
    myJSONStringArray.put(jsonString );
}
String oneHugeCSVString = CDL.toString(myJSONStringArray);
File file = new File("C:\\myCSV.csv");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, oneHugeCSV );
```

for now ignore the main problem in the above code that 'oneHugeCSVString' wont a huge dataset with multiple gigabytes. Biggest failure point. I will break it into multiple strings. But my main question is performance. Am I parsing the XML file twice by converting XML->JSON->CSV, as opposed to directly converting it from XML->CSV. what is the most efficient way to do the above. What XML library I could use to convert from XML to comma separated CSV. Appreciate your input.
thanks a bunch

Sample XMLs extracted form Blob:

```
<document id="123">
<name>Ram</name>
<age>80</age>
<address>
    <line1>myAddressLine1</line1>
    <line2></line2>
    <zip></zip>
</address>
<Education>BSComputerScience</education>
<email>myemail@yahoo.com</email>
<document>

<document id="123">
<name>Rick</name>
<age>67</age>
<address>
    <line1>RicksAddreLine1</line1>
    <line2>RicksAddreLine1</line2>
    <zip>80134</zip>
</address>
<Education>MBBS</education>
<Phone>123454567</Phone>
<document>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a sample input of your xml and the desired csv with the filterd fields?

Comment: Hi Eritrean, added above. thank you

Comment: I have some problems with "All I have is a list of fieldnames that I need to fetch from these blobs." What does it mean exactly? Fieldnames are inadequate to identify values inside an XML document. Usually, you use XPATH for that. Your XML examples are very simple. E.g. you can create a unique "fieldname" by concatenate the element names on the path like addressZip. But is this valid for all your XMLs? What if there are multiple address elements present? Do you take only the first one? Or should you create mulitple rows in your CSV file? Your requirements are unclear and incomplete.

Comment: Here are just a few general thoughts: If your database is able to process XML and XPATH direclty (like Oracle or MS SQL Server), then it would probably make the most sense to extract the values with SQL queries and the vendor specific XML extensions. Otherwise, I would parse each XML individually, extract the individual values with XPATH and use OpenCSV to write them to a CSV file. But you have to first define how you get the XPATH expressions for the given field names and what to do with XMLs which you cannot map one to one to a CSV record (e.g. with multiple address elements present).